# Indicator for missing semicolon at the end of code blocks in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I've noticed that every now and then I've missed a semicolon. I found out its because the indicator that WebStorm shows when a semicolon is missing does not appear for the last line of a code block. For example:

[image]

But later if you adjust the code block and add more lines it becomes invalid:

[image]

How can I get WebStorm to always show the missing semicolon indicator so I can catch it while I'm writing the same line? I already have "**Settings > Editor > Code Style > JavaScript > Other > Use semicolon to terminate statements**" enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warnings/Notices are detected by inspections while Code Style is used for code formatting (automatic (when you code) or on demand).

If you want to rely on your *code style settings alone* then I would suggest to use <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Enter</kbd> to complete your statements.

As for actual inspection: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | JavaScript | Code style issues | Unterminated statement` -- it has special option that affects last statement in the block.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i was after.